# How do we crop a video and then resize it?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

On blender 2.92 I can crop videos to my preference, but then when I render them it just shows a black screen where I cropped it. How do I resize it soo it fills the missing spot? For example making the cropped video larger.

Answer (score 7):

If you can move to 2.93.4 it will be to your advantage because a number of Video Sequence Editor bugs have been fixed.  In this case, it's very easy to do:

[image: Compositing showing the crop and scale settings]

- Use the Crop settings to select the cropping you want.  Here I simply cropped 100 pixels off of each side and the top and bottom.  This leaves the image centered.
- Use the Transform -> Scale X and Transform -> Scale Y settings to expand the cropped image to fit.

Or you can use the compositor to composite the movie into another scene.

Comment: Let's say I just cropped off left and right side by 100 pixels. Is it possible to use transform and fill up all the remaining space without the video looking askew?

Comment: Yes.  That's what Position X and Position Y are for.

Comment: Right now I have my video which has 2 gray strips on both left and right side by 100 pixels. If I use position x all that does is move the video to the respective side making the gray pixels more on the opposite side? Correct me if im wrong. I want to see if I can remove gray pixels completely just video

Comment: You need to both scale and move until it fits